# Como descartar un array vacio en una funcion?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, function

Hola a todos estoy trabajando con js nativo, en esta función regreso el producto de los elementos en el array, lo que no puedo lograr es descartar el caso de un array vacio, siempre me muestra el 1, pero si a result le cambio el valor a 0 no me hace la multiplicación.
Agradezco su ayuda a todos, saludos.

```
function getProductOfAllElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
  var arr = obj[key];
 if(arr === [] || !Array.isArray(arr)){
    return 0;
 }
  else{
    var result = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      result = result *= arr[i];
      console.log(result);
    }
     return result;
  }
}

var obj = {
  key:[1, 2, 3, 4]
};

getProductOfAllElementsAtProperty(obj, 'key');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías considerar evaluar la cantidad de elementos en caso sea un Array, por ejemplo:

```js
function getProductOfAllElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
 var arr = obj[key];
 if(!Array.isArray(arr) || arr.length === 0){
    return 0;
 }
  else{
    var result = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      result = result *= arr[i];      
    }
     return result;
  }
}

var obj = {key:[1, 2, 3, 4]};
console.log(getProductOfAllElementsAtProperty(obj, 'key'));

obj = {key:[]};
console.log(getProductOfAllElementsAtProperty(obj, 'key'));

obj = {key:"nombre"};
console.log(getProductOfAllElementsAtProperty(obj, 'key'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que tu pregunta es por qué cuando el array está vacío no cumple la condición `arr === []`.

En javascript existen los tipos de valores "primitivos" o "tipos por valor". Esto implica que estos valores son inmutables y que cuando se accede al valor de una variable con un "valor primitivo" se accede directamente al valor. De esta forma si dos variables tienen el valor primitivo `3` y se comparan, serán iguales ya que sus valores son iguales:

```js
var a = 3;
var b = 3;
var c = 4;
console.log('a y b tienen el valor 3 y son iguales:', a===b);
console.log('a y c tienen diferentes valores y son diferentes:', a===c);
```

El resto de tipos son objetos o "tipos por referencia". Estos valores pueden ser modificables (se puede añadir propiedades o métodos, cambiar los valores de las propiedades, añadir o cambiar elementos de un array...) y las variables lo que contienen es una referencia al objeto. De esta forma cuando se comparan dos variables con objetos los valores que se comparan son las referencias (punteros) a los objetos, es decir, dos variables serán iguales si tienen referencias al mismo objeto, no si hacen referencia a dos objetos iguales:

```js
var a = { prop: 4 };
var b = { prop: 4 };
var c = a;
console.log('a y b hacen referencia a diferentes objetos:', a===b);
console.log('a y c hacen referencia al mismo objeto: ', a===c);
```

Podemos ver la diferencia si modificamos el valor de la propiedad `prop` del ejemplo actual en cada uno de los objetos:

```js
var a = { prop: 4 };
var b = { prop: 4 };
var c = a;
console.log('a y b hacen referencia a diferentes objetos:', a===b);
console.log('a y c hacen referencia al mismo objeto: ', a===c);

a.prop = 5;
console.log('a.prop ahora es 5:', a.prop);
console.log('c.prop también es 5:', c.prop);
console.log('b hace referencia a otro objeto por lo que b.prop sigue siendo 4:', b.prop);
```

Lo mismo sucede con los arrays:

```js
var a = [];
var b = [];
var c = a;
console.log('a y b hacen referencia a diferentes arrays (aunque los dos estén vacíos):', a===b);
console.log('a y c hacen referencia al mismo array: ', a===c);
```

Espero haberlo aclarado un poco.